# Error messages by testing Angularjs with Karma and Jasmine are to large

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am about to write some AngularJS unit-tests with jasmine using the Karma-server, everything works fine except the error-messages when something unexpected happens, the whole error-message is so large that i can't even see the first message line on my terminal because it reach the limit of terminal length-size.

Is there a solution to show only the error-message and hide the console-dump ?

thank you for helping me and sorry for bad English ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you use [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com/), you can specify how many lines you want to see, you could increase it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on window. You can try to `right click` on the `icon` of the console window => select `Properties` => choice tab `Layout` => at `Screen buffer size` section set the `Height:` to what ever you want. (I use it at 500 quite enough for me)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions, but the problem about the terminal was only to describe how large the "error-report" is.

I just want to manipulate the console-output of the socket.io for a readable report.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, just install the plugin [karma-mocha-report](https://github.com/litixsoft/karma-mocha-reporter) and set this configuration to karme.conf:

```js
mochaReporter: {
    output: 'noFailures'
},
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Start:
  serverProvider servcie
    ✔ should step the sourceURL and strip it correctly
    ✔ should handle succeeded repsonse
    ✔ should handle failed response
    ✔ should provide the cached mc-services
    ✔ should update the cache
  Name of the group
    ✖ should behave...

Finished in 0.079 secs / 0.061 secs

SUMMARY:
✔ 5 tests completed
✖ 1 tests failed
```

The output option 'minimal' does not work well, i get the terminal overloaded even with this option.